# Issue with Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolPropsBase.ResetMaxWidth

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

Currently I am migrating .net windows application from framework 4.0 to 4.5 and the application is using Infragistics controls. As per the requirement, migration includes that I should replace Infragistics controls with Microsoft controls. To view the design form in 4.0 I am getting the error as below

```
    Show Call Stack 

    Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolPropsBase.ResetMaxWidth()
```

Please help me on how to resolve this and the application is using Infragistics version 3.2

Please refer the below screen shot for the error.

[image: infragistics error]g

Comment: I'm quite sure `Show Call Stack` is a link in VS, not an error. What exact error do you get?

Comment: @BastiM, Thank you Basti . I have copied the screen shot of the error.